# What is the difference in meaning and usage between "stop this" and "stop with this"?

Tags: difference

Could you tell me what the difference in meaning and usage is between *stop this* and *stop with this*? For example:

> You are complaining way too much. **Stop this**.
>
> You are complaining way too much. **Stop with this**.

Comment: _Stop with this_ is unidiomatic in my (British ) English - and, by the way, you mean _too much_.

Comment: stop with this is unidiomatic in any English. However, it might be said. Did you make this up  yourself?

Comment: No, I didn't make it up. I've heard people say it.

Comment: I have heard people say it (in the Northeastern US), although it is not common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop this is standard; stop *with* this (or something) is East Coast/New York area US Yiddish or Yiddish  influenced dialect, e.g. *Stop with the kvetching!*

> Nudnik:   A persistent bore. He doesn't stop with the talking, the
> asking, the annoying till you want to staple his lips together.

[The Yiddish Dictionary of Fools](https://www.aish.com/j/fs/48929367.html)

Comment: Yes, basically, I agree. But it requires that the....